# being served prime rib when asked for ribeye steak

Tags: cut-of-meat

Last night I was served prime rib when I specifically requested rib eye steak. Is this a normal practice in restaurants?  I understand that the meat is the same, that the cooking process is what differs.  Although I do enjoy prime rib, it is not at all the same as a grilled rib eye steak.  This happened at a restaurant that has received awards at the state level and is well known for their steaks.

Comment: Was ribeye steak offered on their menu?

Comment: *Is this a normal practice in restaurants*. Worldwide?

Comment: How was it served vs how did you want it? How was it cooked vs what did the menu say? They are both from the rib roast.  The ribeye is cut from the rib section before cooking, while prime rib is is cut from the rib roast after it has been cooked. So this sounds like a miscommunication of some sort.

Comment: With the popularity of sous-vide cooking, it's also possible that you'd get the coloring like prime rib in the middle and a much thinner layer of crust than you're used to with a steak.  Was the cut of meat browned on both sides, or was it still pink?

Answer (score 8):

No. A dish is a combination of the ingredients and the techniques used to make it.

- a cheese omelet served in a pie crust isn't a quiche
- and a dish of oily raw eggs with lemon juice isn't mayonnaise
- a salad with lettuce, tomato, bacon, mayo, and croutons isn't a BLT

If you brought it to their attention and they said your order was correct, they were either pulling your leg, it's some weird idiosyncrasy at their restaurant, or they have no idea what they're doing.

If you didn't bring it to their attention, they almost certainly inadvertently served you the wrong dish. *This happens all the time.* Being a server is an extremely fast-paced, difficult job where you've got to remember a million things at once. Maybe the point of sale system had a "Ribeye" button right next to something like a "Rib Lge" button for a large prime rib cut. Mistakes do happen, and if you don't let anybody know, they can't correct them.